# PHP imagefilter and uploadify

Tags: php, gd, uploadify, imagefilter

I have a question on how to filter image while moving the file. I used uploadify to upload image. What I did is, before he move the image to the directory, the code filter will covert the image to grayscale.

Here is my code

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    $newImg = imagefilter($tempFile, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); // This is what I insert

    move_uploaded_file($newImg,$targetFile);
    echo "1";
}
```

The code is uploadify.php and I just inserted a filter to make it grayscale. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on how i can make the image to grayscale before moving it to the directory

Comment: `imagefilter()` works on an image resource that you need to initialize first using the appropriate `imagecreatefrom*()` function. See the [manual on `imagefilter`](http://www.php.net/imagefilter) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Imagefilter works on an image resource, not a file, and also a boolean, not a new image. It's probably worth reading through [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php), but you'll need to change your code to something along these lines

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Create an image resource - exact method will depend on the image type (PNG, JPEG, etc)
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($tempFile);

    // Apply your filter
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

    // Save your changes
    imagepng($im, $tempFile);

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `imagefilter` you have to load image first. Use one of GD load functions ( like: [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)). 
Then you can use filter on **loaded image**. By the way check parameters for [`imagefilter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) (which requires loaded image, not path to image). Here is some example code (that replaces your `imagefilter()`):

```
// Check extension of the file, here is example if the file is png, but you have to check for extension and use specified function
$img = imagecreatefrompng($tempFile);

if( imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE) )
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // failture
}

// Save file as png to $targetFile
imagepng($img, $targetFile);

// Destroy useless resource
imagedestroy($img);
```